# Allow only local users in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to restrict the access for some VHosts so that only 127.0.0.1 can access it. I always used something like this to bind the VHost to the localhost and not the external IP:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name myvhost.local;
    location / {
        ....
    }
}
```

But I noticed that some tutorials also include explicit `allow` directives for the localhost and expicitly deny all others:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name myvhost.local;
    location / {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        ...
    }
}
```

Are these `allow`/`deny` directives really needed when I already listen only at 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Try changing the allow line to: `allow 127.0.0.1/32;`

Comment: My question is whether I need that `allow` at all because I set `listen` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: You don't need to, but it's a good practice

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `listen` directive tells the operating system on what interface the web server binds itself. So, when you look at `netstat -a` after starting nginx, you will see that nginx listens only on 127.0.0.1 IP port 80, which means that the nginx server cannot be reached via any other interface.

Binding to a specific IP address works in a lower level in the actual network stack than the `allow` / `deny` directives inside nginx configuration.

This means that you don't need separate `allow` / `deny` directives inside your configuration with your use case, because the connections are limited lower in the network stack.

If you specify `listen 80;` only, and use `allow` / `deny` directives, then nginx will send a HTTP error code to the client, tellng that access is denied.

With the `listen 127.0.0.1;` case, the browser cannot connect to the server at all, because there is no TCP port open for the browser to connect to.

Comment: Okay, I forgot to mention that I have some more VHosts and some of them are bound not only to localhost. All of them (local-only and non-local) are running on the same nginx-instance. Thus `netstat` shows a local address of `0.0.0.0:80` (all interfaces). Can I then still omit `deny`/`allow` on the local-only servers?

Comment: In this case, nginx will show the contents of the virtual host that has been defined with `listen 80 default_server;` directive when a client asks for a vhost bound to `127.0.0.1:80`. If you don't have a `default_server` defined, then it will show a server that has `listen 80;` defined.

Comment: OK, so there is no possibility that non-local users can access `listen 127.0.0.1`-servers and I don't even need `allow/deny` on these servers?

Comment: Yes, there is no possibility for that.

Comment: This answers the question, unlike the current top answer. Why is it not top?

Answer (score 21):

Let's say your network ID is `192.168.1.0`, edit your conf file like so:

```
location / {
  # block one workstation
  deny    192.168.1.1;
  # allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24
  allow   192.168.1.0/24;
  # drop rest of the world
  deny    all;
}
```

Please let me know how it works for you.

Edit #1:

Yes, the allow directive is a must according to the [Official Nginx wiki](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/).
Their example is:

```
location / {
    allow 192.168.1.1/24;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny 192.168.1.2;
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: I really want to limit the access to `127.0.0.1` ;) My question is whether I need that `allow` at all because I already set `listen` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Please check Edit #1.

Comment: Sry, I don't think you understand my question ;) What you've posted is (more or less) already what I've wrote in my question above. But that's not an answer to my question.

Comment: @Biggie You don't have to limit access to 127.0.0.1, it is only available on the local machine.

Comment: Presumably this is all true, but it specifically does not answer OP's question! The acccepted answer does.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to achieve the same functionality (allow only local users in nginx) and I figured out that I can do something simple like this:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /path/to/folder;
    }       

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

This config file works fine for me, I am not using any `allow` directive, but only `127.0.0.1:80`, and with that I am able to restrict nginx access to local users only!

Comment: great and simple answer for limiting to local users.